# Vertically center a table on a landscape page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a landscape page with one table on it. My current code horizontally centers the table, but how can I also vertically center it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{center}
 \resizebox{27cm}{!}{

  \begin{tabular}{|*7c|}
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Column 1} &
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Column 2} &
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Column 3} &
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Column 4} \\
  \hline
  1. Row & a & b & c & d & e & f \\ 
  \hline 
  % more lines here
  \end{tabular} 
 }

\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

I omitted a the remaining rows here for the sake of clarity, but they don't occupy more than 50% of the page, so there is still plenty of space at the bottom.
Putting the `tabular` in a `table` with `\centering` (as often suggested in that case) fails with `Not in outer par mode.` I assume that it's due to the adjustbox and resizebox.

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}` before and after the adjustbox. You will perhaps have to add some additional `\vspace` to correct the difference in the margins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\vspace*{\fill}` before and after the adjustbox. You will perhaps have to add some additional `\vspace` to correct the difference in the margins.